# Disabling -msse

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I am trying to run various benchmark tests using CPU2006 to see what various optimizations do in terms of speed on gcc. I am familiar with -O1, -O2, and -O3, but have heard that -msse is a decent optimization. What exactly is -msse? I've also seen that -msse is default on a 64 bit architecture, so how do I disable it to compare the difference between using it and not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.justskins.com/forums/gcc-option-msse-and-128289.html

SSE (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) as the name says are the SSE instructions present in processors since Pentium 3. They are fast for some kind of vectorial and floating point computation. They are available in all 64 bit processors, so why should we disable them?

You can choose between -msse and -msse2. SSE2 are another instruction set built over SSE that add other powerful and very fast vectorial instructions.

Pentium 3 did have SSE, and is a 32 bit processor.
SSE2 is more modern instead, Pentium 4, that is still a 32 bit processor, have SSE2.

Comment: We are trying various combinations of benchmarks including switching between 32 bit and 64 bit compilations, so we are just curious to see what disabling -msse would do.

Comment: You can choose between `-msse`, `-msse2`, `-msse3`, `-msse4.1`, and `-msse4.2`. Although for "real" use, it's probably better to just target a CPU generation instead of specific extensions.

Comment: SSE instructions are used only in some optimized version of memset and memcpy or when the compiler can understand it can be a better optimization, but sse and sse2 have so much requirements, for example memory alignment, that they are used rarely. I would not be surprised if your program will make no difference if compiled with -msse or with -mno-msse

Comment: I must admit i never used -msse3, -msse4.1 and -msse4.2 :) good to know, thanks inerdia.

Answer (score 6):

`-msse` activates the generation of SSE instructions. All 64-bit processors (x86-64) have them, but some older 32-bit processors (IA-32) do not have these instructions. This is the reason for GCC's default settings.

`SSE` instructions have to do with vector operations and floating-point. Considering that opportunities for automatic vectorization are rare in general-purpose code, the only difference you are likely to observe are if you use floating-point.

On 64-bit, to disable SSE instructions, use `-mno-sse`

Comment: Pentium 3 did have it, but is a 32 bit processor. SSE2 is more modern instead, and not all 32 bit processor have it but some of them have it. Pentium 4 is a 32 bit processor but have SSE2.

Comment: @Salvatore I am not sure what you mean. All Intel IA32 processors from the 386 to the Pentium II are 32-bit processors without SSE. I will clarify my answer, but I meant that all x86-64 processors have SSE but not all IA32 processors have it. SSE2, as an extension of SSE, is of course supported only by a subset of the processors that support SSE.