# How can I compile *without* various instruction sets enabled?

Tags: gcc, intel, gnu, compiler-optimization

I am attempting to recompile some software with various instruction sets, specifically, `SSE`, `SSE2`, `SSE3`, `SSSE3`, `SSE4.1`, `SSE4.2`, and `AVX`, and I would like to see how the code performs *without* these instruction sets to make sure I am getting the full effect of them.

For example, I want to compile it with just `-O2` with a `gnu` compiler and see how it performs when restricting it to *only* `SSE`, to see which flags it is invoking by default. I also have an `intel` compiler that I am working with and I would like to isolate what each flag (or combination of flags) is doing to my code, so how can I specify *exactly* which flags are being invoked?

If it matters, I am working with `C`, `C++`, and `Fortran` on `Linux`.

Comment: Which version of GCC? They changed a lot of the flags from 4.8 -> 4.9.

Comment: The appropriate answer is 'yes'. We have gcc 4.2.1, 4.4.7, 4.5.2, 4.8.1, and various versions of icc. I would like to compare runtimes, efficiency, etc. on each one.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7894633/3488231) be a duplicate?

Comment: Try something like `-march=pentium3`. On x64, you won't be able to go below SSE2 since all x64 has SSE2. You can also selectively disable them with `-mno-avx` and such.

Answer (score 5):

For `GCC` compiler:
You have to use `-mno-`options for doing it.

> These switches **enable or disable** the use of instructions in the MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, AVX, AVX2, AVX512F, AVX512PF, AVX512ER, AVX512CD, SHA, AES, PCLMUL, FSGSBASE, RDRND, F16C, FMA, SSE4A, FMA4, XOP, LWP, ABM, BMI, BMI2, FXSR, XSAVE, XSAVEOPT, LZCNT, RTM, or 3DNow! extended instruction sets. These extensions are also available as built-in functions: see X86 Built-in Functions, for details of the functions enabled and disabled by these switches.

More info you can find on [official GCC site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html)

For `ICC` compiler, you have to use
combination of :

> -march=”cpu” optimize for a specific cpu
>   -mtune=”cpu” produce code only for a specific cpu
>   -msse3,-msse4,-mavx, etc. level of SIMD and vector
>   instructions

[More info here](https://wiki.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/7/77/Snug_techtalk_compiler.pdf)